# application setup loop

Tags: facebook-apps

I started to create my first facebook app for my website yesterday, but texting to my phone was required to complete the process. Today I turned on texting and am trying to complete the process.

I have tried several app names and repeatedly get looped through the code verification and dumped back to entering the app name, then code verification endlessly.

How do I break out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could try verifying with a credit card - they do not charge anything.  I live in Israel and many developers here i've talked to were also unable to verify by phone.